# NodeJs and node-postgres code is not returning any response in EC2

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-ec2, node-postgres

I am trying to connect to a remote Postgresql instance (Aurora) using Node and the pg (https://node-postgres.com/) library.

My code looks like this:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const pool = new Pool({
  user: '-not-shown-',
  host: '-not-shown-',
  database: '-not-shown-',
  password: '-not-shown-',
  port: 5432,
});
console.log('Testing select now query...');
pool.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res);
  pool.end();
  if (!err) {
    console.log(res);
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

However, I get no result whatsoever. Neither the query result or any sort of error.
Note that I am able to successfully connect to the database instance using psql in the commandline.
I am using an EC2 Free tier Amazon Linux 2 AMI instance.

The code works on my local machine and I get a result that looks like this:
[image]

But when I ssh into the Ec2 machine, all I get is this:
[image]

Notice, no result and no error either.
I do not know what is going on.
I assume there is a problem, since it would have returned the query result if it was ok.
Please help.

Comment: Did you hardcode the machine public IP (as database IP) in code? If yes, try with "localhost"  instead. As well as check your node server logs.

Answer (score -1):

Update:

I found the answer:
https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2069

The current versions of node-postgres and pg-promise are not compatible with the latest version of node. I was using Node 14. I downgraded to 12 and it is now working perfectly.

Comment: That is not true. If you actually follow the very link you provided, you will see that the issue existed only in the library versions prior to 8.0.3. It was fixed some time ago, and the latest versions do not have any issue with NodeJS v14. Check your version of the library.